# WCF Service Side Timeout not executing

Tags: c#, wcf

I have a WCF Services that is configured to use basichttpbinding.I want to test server-side timeout but I cannot see any changes when changing my config.

Here is my binding:

```
    <binding name="DefaultBasicBinding" closeTimeout="00:00:30" openTimeout="00:00:30" sendTimeout="00:00:30" maxBufferSize="4194304" maxBufferPoolSize="4194304" maxReceivedMessageSize="4194304">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="100" maxStringContentLength="1000000" maxArrayLength="1000000" maxBytesPerRead="1000000" />
    </binding>
```

I've researched quite a bit and could not make it work.
I'm using a wcf test client to invoke the service in question, which has a client side timeout of 10 minutes.

I also have a service behavior that has a transaction timeout of 30 seconds.
The service is hosted in IIS locally, where compilation debug is set to false and the httpruntime execution timeout is set to 30 seconds.

```
    <httpRuntime executionTimeout="30" maxRequestLength="67108864"/>
```

My service call persists of a service that eventually calls a timed stored procedure of 1 minute and a half. Everytime I invoke the service it executes successfully.

When I change the send timeout to anything under a minute, I see no difference.

It seems like there is no answer anywhere, and I’ve also read that WCF doesn’t support service side timeouts?

I need a helping hand on this one. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This might help... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1149507/wcf-server-side-timeout

Answer (score 0):

There are four timeout values involved in the process. 
Three of them are involved at client side and only 1 applies at Server Side.

### Client Side

openTimeout: Timeout kicks in when you try to open connection with WCF. 
closeTimeout: Timeout kicks in when you try to close connection with WCF. 
sendTimeout: This is the timeout that specifies how long the client can wait for the transport to complete data writing until throwing exception.

### Server Side

ReceiveTimeout: This is the timeout that specifies how long the service can wait from the beginning of receiving a request until the message is processed. It’s server-side setting. When you send a large message to the service and the service needs long time to process, you would need to increase this setting.

If I understood correct then you need to play with RecieveTimeout at Server side to achieve your desired results.

Comment: I can try that out, but from what I am reading, it's not exactly the case. Where the open close and send are all configurable via server as well.

Comment: I can try regardless to play with the timeout, and see what happens. I'll come back to you!

Answer (score 0):

Brief summary of binding timeout knobs...

Client side:

SendTimeout is used to initialize the OperationTimeout, which governs the whole interaction for sending a message (including receiving a reply message in a request-reply case).  This timeout also applies when sending reply messages from a CallbackContract method.
OpenTimeout and CloseTimeout are used when opening and closing channels (when no explicit timeout value is passed).
ReceiveTimeout is not used.
Server side:

Send, Open, and Close Timeout same as on client (for Callbacks).
ReceiveTimeout is used by ServiceFramework layer to initialize the session-idle timeout.

From this [post](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/84551e45-19a2-4d0d-bcc0-516a4041943d/explaination-of-different-timeout-types?forum=wcf). take a look and recheck your configs.